# Read Csv from s3 bucket with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Need some help, I have a AWS lambda, I am getting data from csv and parsing it in order to count the total amount of rows in the csv.

I have tried different ways to count the rows and storage that information in an output bucket.
Here is my last try to do it. I having an ouput but not counting the rows. I have the console.log executions and see that the rowCount variable increasing but it's not increased in the output doc.

```
import { S3 } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { parse } from 'csv';

const s3 = new S3();
let rowCount = 0;

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  // Download the file from the input bucket
  const doc = await s3.getObject(params);

  doc.Body.pipe(
    parse({
      delimiter: ",",
      columns: true,
    })
    .on('data', function (row) {
        console.log(row);
        rowCount++;
        console.log(rowCount)
      })

    .on('end', async function(){
        console.log(rowCount)
    })
  )
  
  const date = new Date().toLocaleString();
  const outputBucket = 'outputbucket';
  const outputKey = 'output.txt';
  const outputParams = {
    Bucket: outputBucket,
    Key: outputKey,
    Body: `Processed ${rowCount} rows in file ${key} from ${bucket} on ${date}`,
  };
      
  await s3.putObject(outputParams)

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes made to fix the issue of rowCount variable not being updated correctly and the output text file not being generated were based on waiting for the CSV file processing to complete before creating the output text file. This was achieved by creating a promise that resolves once the CSV file processing is completed, and using await to wait for the promise to resolve before creating the output text file. This ensures that the rowCount variable is updated correctly before creating the output text file.

```
import { S3 } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { parse } from 'csv';


const s3 = new S3();

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  let rowCount = 0;

  const doc = await s3.getObject(params);

  const processCsvPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doc.Body.pipe(
      parse({
        delimiter: ',',
        columns: true,
      })
    )
      .on('data', function (row) {
        console.log(row);
        rowCount++;
      })
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log(`Rows: ${rowCount}`);
        resolve();
      });
  });

  await processCsvPromise;

  const date = new Date().toLocaleString();
  const outputBucket = 'outputbucket';
  const outputKey = 'output.txt';
  const outputParams = {
    Bucket: outputBucket,
    Key: outputKey,
    Body: `${rowCount} rows in the file ${key} from ${bucket} at ${date}`,
  };
  await s3.putObject(outputParams);
};
```